# Links disabled in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Seems a very strange problem to me, but the links on this site (www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird) are disabled in internet explorer. It seems to work fine on all the other browsers I've tested. The problem seems to be that internet explorer doesn't recognise them as links.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Edit: also, form inputs are not recognised as such.

Here's the HTML header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>bird</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird/wp-content/themes/birdtheme/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="http://www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird/wp-content/themes/birdtheme/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="http://www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird/wp-content/themes/birdtheme/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird/wp-content/themes/birdtheme/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird/wp-content/themes/birdtheme/css/custom-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird/wp-content/themes/birdtheme/img/favicon.ico">
    <meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=3.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.dartsocialmedia.co.uk/bird/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.5.2" />
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
  </head>
```

Comment: **Please, show some code.**

Comment: I honestly don't know where to start. There are several CSS files, but I can't think what could possibly be causing it - such a strange fault. I've posted the HTML head if that helps.

Comment: Is this your site? Or are you using it as _design inspiration_?

Comment: Not sure why that's relevant. It is indeed my site.

Comment: for me is working.. maybe is css, put the code. but remember IE is a demon friend.

Comment: It's relevant, because I would advise you some other resource for inspiration depending on the answer to my previous comment... Anyway, try adding `zoom: 1;` to the element that doesn't work. This triggers hasLayout in IE browsers. It helps in many cases. Give it a try. Also consider `z-index` at a higher level something like e.g. 9999. What kind of IE support do you need? IE 7 and higher?

Comment: Try changing <html> tag to <!Doctype html>

Comment: @ArunAravind: I presume you mean add the doctype before the `<html>` tag. A doctype is not an alternative element.

Comment: yep that's what i meant. Never use it. I read somewhere that IE behaves wierd when it is not there. So just passed on. Sry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that `z-index: 999` in your css file at line 5 cause the problem.

I suggest you change your CSS bacause `body:before` overlap the whole window:

1) Implements the border into the body element, add:

```
body {
    border: 5px solid #dd127b;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

2) Use the body:before to place the top border with fixed position to hide overflow when scrolling:

```
body:before {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #dd127b;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background: #111;
    padding-top: 10px;
    z-index: 999; 
}
```

3) Use the body:after to place the bottom border:

```
body:after {
    border-top: 5px solid #dd127b;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background: #111;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: It's for the border round the edge. So that's hiding the content underneath?

Comment: can you put the css for this: id="mobile-nav-list" and class="scrollPage"?

Comment: Better than using the body:before is using the wrapper or implements the border directly to the body element.